# On Linux, how to draw a text to a bitmap?

Tags: c++, linux, text, bitmap, draw

Suppose I have allocated a 2-D array int bitmap[WIDTH][HEIGHT]. I wish to let the Linux system draw a line of text, say "Hello World.", to this bitmap buffer as if Linux is printing a normal text on screen, so that I can extract the bitmap pattern of the text and combine it with my other bitmap images. So, could you please share a C++ snippet for this purpose that works on Linux? Thanks a lot.

PS: I can find some codes that do the job, but they are on Windows, not Linux.
PS2: If you don't happen to have the code, you can teach me how to write the code, but please expect a lot of naive questions on Linux C++ programming to follow.

Comment: Maybe `cairo` is worth looking at: http://zetcode.com/gfx/cairo/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I later used [OpenImageIO](https://sites.google.com/site/openimageio/) to accomplish this. The C++ code is as follows:

```
#include <OpenImageIO/imageio.h> 
#include <OpenImageIO/imagebuf.h>
#include <OpenImageIO/imagebufalgo.h>
OIIO_NAMESPACE_USING

const int WIDTH = 256, HEIGHT = 32, CHANNELS = 3;
unsigned char buffer[WIDTH * HEIGHT * CHANNELS];

int main() {
    ImageBuf ib(ImageSpec(WIDTH, HEIGHT, CHANNELS), buffer);
    ImageBufAlgo::render_text(ib, 0 /* x */, 10 /* y */,
        "Hello, world!" /* text to draw */);
    for (int j = 0; j < HEIGHT; j++)
        for (int i = 0; i < WIDTH; i++)
            cout << buffer[(i+j*WIDTH)*CHANNELS+0] << ","    //R
                 << buffer[(i+j*WIDTH)*CHANNELS+1] << ","    //G
                 << buffer[(i+j*WIDTH)*CHANNELS+2] << endl;  //B
}
```

The bitmap pattern can be illustrated as the following screenshot (using `ib.write("output.tif");`):

[image]

Thank Larry Gritz for helping me out.

PS: It is tested on ubuntu 14.04 and g++ 4.8.4. The link option used is `-lboost_system -lOpenImageIO`.

> More often than not, it is harder to understand a question than to
>   answer it.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to choose a C or C++  graphics library. [Qt](https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_for_Beginners) and [SDL](https://www.libsdl.org/) are two good choices.

=========================================================================

If all you want is to draw an image, another choice is [libGD](https://libgd.github.io/) (along with the aforementioned [Qt](https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_for_Beginners) and [SDL](https://www.libsdl.org/)).

Jere is an example:

https://cs.marlboro.edu/code/c/GD_example/GD_example.c

```
include <stdio.h>
#include <gd.h>

// Dimensions of image in pixels
#define IMAGE_WIDTH  300
#define IMAGE_HEIGHT 300

// The data to display is in a DATA_SIZE x DATA_SIZE array,
// which will have its (left,top)=(x,y) corner at 
// (DATA_TOP, DATA_LEFT) pixels in from the (0,0)=(left,top) pixel.
#define DATA_SIZE    8
#define DATA_LEFT    30
#define DATA_TOP     30

// Position of some blue lines drawn in the image.
#define BORDER       10
#define LEFT         BORDER
#define RIGHT        IMAGE_WIDTH - BORDER
#define TOP          BORDER
#define BOTTOM       IMAGE_HEIGHT - BORDER

// See the bottom of this code for a discussion of some output possibilities.
char*   filename =   "GD_example.png";

// Some values that'll go into the image as shades of gray.
// Range is 0 to 255 (i.e. 8 bits, which is the standard range of intensity).
// To do this sort of thing with floating point data or other data,
// you'd first scale your numbers to be in this 0 to 255 range.
int     data[DATA_SIZE][DATA_SIZE] ={
  {  2,  10,  10,  10,  10,  10,  10,   2},
  { 10,  20,  30,  40,  40,  30,  20,  10},
  { 10,  30, 100, 100, 100, 100,  30,  10},
  { 10,  40, 100, 200, 200, 100,  40,  10},
  { 10,  30, 100, 200, 200, 100,  30,  10},
  { 10,  20, 100, 100, 100, 100,  20,  10},
  { 10,  10,  20,  30,  40,  30,  10,  10},
  {  2,  10,  10,  10,  10,  10,  10,   2}
};
int main(){
  FILE*       outfile;                                  // defined in stdio
  gdImagePtr  image;                                    // a GD image object
  int         white, blue, gray[255];                   // some GD colors 
  int         i, x, y;                                  // array subscripts

  printf("=== GD example ===\n");

  printf("Creating %i by %i image.\n", IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_HEIGHT);
  image = gdImageCreate(IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_HEIGHT);
  // Or image = gdImageCreateTrueColor(IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_HEIGHT);
  //    followed by colors like white=gdTrueColor(255,255,255) that don't
  //    need to refer to any one image's color table.
  white = gdImageColorAllocate(image, 255,255,255);    //  1st is background
  blue  = gdImageColorAllocate(image, 0,0,255);        //  (red,green,blue)
  for (i=0; i<255; i++){
    gray[i] = gdImageColorAllocate(image, i,i,i);
  }

  printf("Drawing some blue lines.\n");
  gdImageLine(image, LEFT,TOP,     RIGHT,TOP,    blue); // draw lines in image
  gdImageLine(image, RIGHT,TOP,    RIGHT,BOTTOM, blue); //  +-----------------+
  gdImageLine(image, RIGHT,BOTTOM, LEFT,BOTTOM,  blue); //  |0,0       WIDTH,0|
  gdImageLine(image, LEFT,BOTTOM,  LEFT,TOP,     blue); //  |0,HEIGHT         |
                                                        //  +-----------------+
  printf("Filling in some gray pixels.\n");
  for (x=0; x<DATA_SIZE; x++){                          // fill some grayscale
    for (y=0; y<DATA_SIZE; y++){                        // colors from data.
      gdImageSetPixel(image, x+DATA_LEFT, y+DATA_TOP, gray[data[x][y]]);    
    }
  }

  // Finally, write the image out to a file.
  printf("Creating output file '%s'.\n", filename);
  outfile = fopen(filename, "wb");
  gdImagePng(image, outfile);
  fclose(outfile);
}
```

Comment: For simply drawing to an image, libGD is another good choice.